# Prevent state saving for specific element

Tags: jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I have the following scenario:

I have a dataTable in which I have a column with the following code

```
<f:facet name="header">
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox styleClass="checkall"
        id="my-id-chk" />
    <h:outputLabel for="my-id-chk" />
</f:facet>
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox rendered="#{row.selectable}" value="#{row.selected}"
    styleClass="checkall_remover" id="row-chk" />
<h:outputLabel for="row-chk" />
```

When I want to select all rows and delete them:

1) I click on the `h:selectBooleanCheckbox` in the `<f:facet name="header">` and with js I select all rows checkboxes

2) Click on delete button that `execute` that `dataTable` and deletes all rows on server , that delete button also `renders` the `dataTable` so the deleted rows will be removed from it

Now the thing is that the `h:selectBooleanCheckbox` in the `<f:facet name="header">` keeps its state (checked state)

How can I make that `h:selectBooleanCheckbox` in the `<f:facet name="header">` to be unchecked ?

**The solution that I use right now is** to render the `dataTable` from a "proxy" button that is located in other `h:form` **<--** Using that technique causes the `h:selectBooleanCheckbox` in the `<f:facet name="header">` not to remember its state.

But I prefer a cleaner solution without using additional `h:form`

(I use MyFaces 2.2.3 with Tomcat 7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use plain HTML. JSF state is indeed saved on server side, but HTML state not.

```
<f:facet name="header">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkall"
        id="my-id-chk" />
    <label for="my-id-chk" />
</f:facet>
```

An alternative would be to create a custom component whereby getters/setters don't delegate to `UIComponent#getStateHelper()` but instead to local properties.

Comment: Good one! Going for the plain HTML, thanks BalusC :)